# centering vertically text in a div

Tags: html, css

I have [this div](http://jsfiddle.net/1tjr6r2q/) which contains some text inside a square. I want the text inside to be shown right in the middle of it - it seems that **the bottom** of my text is in the middle, while I would like the middle of my text to be in the middle.

My css is:

```
.touch {
border-radius: 3px;
background: #eee4da;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
/*z-index: 10;*/
font-size: 30px; 
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
/*vertical-align: middle;*/
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2939914/20126

Comment: There are several ways, one is to add `line-height: 60px;` to `.touch` if the text won't wrap and it will always fit on one line. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1tjr6r2q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `height` and add `padding` to the element. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/1tjr6r2q/2/).

CSS:

```
.touch {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #eee4da;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px; 
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}


.grid-row {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

The centering is working on multiple elements as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/1tjr6r2q/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
line-height: 60px; // same as div's height
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tjr6r2q/6/)

Comment: @Arbel - So why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Arbel sorry. i didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) solution, just add "display: table-cell;"

```
.touch {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #eee4da;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*z-index: 10;*/
    font-size: 30px; 
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```